# Number of Isolated Edges in G(n,p)

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I am attempting to find the number of isolated edges in the Erdos - Renyi graph G(n,p). I need to find the formula for the expected number of isolated edges. I've broken the equation down into

$$E[X] = \sum_{u\neq v}E[\deg(v)=1]E[deg(u)=1]E[(u,v)\in \mathrm{Edge}(G(n,p))]$$

so,

$$E[X] = (n-1)\left[n\binom{n-1}{1}p(1-p)^(n-2)\right]^2\binom{n}{2}p $$

Does this seem like the correct method to use?

Comment: Your equations are difficult to read. Please make sure I've converted them correctly.

Comment: $$X = \sum_{v \in G} \mathbf{1}_{[deg(v) = 0]}$$ and then use linearity of expectation. I think the answer should be $n (1-p)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Ben: That's the expected number of isolated vertices, not of isolated edges.

Answer (score 2):

You're calculating as if the three events whose probabilities you're multiplying were independent, but they're far from independent.

The probability for a given edge to exist and be isolated is $p(1-p)^{2(n-2)}$, where the factor of $p$ is for the edge to exist and the $2(n-2)$ factors of $1-p$ are for the remaining $2(n-2)$ edges of the endpoints of the edge not to exist. Thus the expected number of isolated edges is

$$
\binom n2p(1-p)^{2(n-2)}\;.
$$